# Prove equilvalence of generating series with compositions.

Tags: combinatorics, notation, generating-functions

[image]

weight function: w(c1, ..., ck) = c1 + ... + ck and w(ci) = ci, 1<=i<=k

Could someone explain to me what the N notation stand for? My take would be that the left N notation represents a set where each element is a composition of "k" parts and each composition add up to >= 1.

Also, I looked at the product lemma:
[image]

but still couldn't figure out how the solution jumped to the right side.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H3llo there,

the superscript "k" of the N notation stands for compositions with "k" parts and the subscript ">=1" means that each part in each composition is >=1.

Now, let's move on to why those 2 expressions are equal. Here's an extended proof. Hopefully, it'll be more clear:

[image]

As you can see, the product lemma is applied and we result in the expression on the right side.

Your welcome. I can't believe you couldn't figure this out. What a dummy.

P.S. PAINT USERS UNITE!!